# Duplicate a package in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wrote a package in eclipse (Java/Android package, that is). Now I want to make another package which is a slight variation on the original. My plan is to copy and paste each .java file into the new package and change the *import package.somename* to the name of the new package, and develop from there. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the package in the project explorer, press Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V, Eclipse will prompt with a package name conflict warning and ask you to enter a new package name. Just enter it and Eclipse will repackage all copied classes accordingly.

---

Unrelated to the problem, there's a design smell in your approach :)

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is I made an Android App and put it up on the market. Now I want to put up a free demo version, with some functionality removed. I figured the simplest way to do it is to just copy everything and change a few things.

Comment: Fair enough. Did the answer help?

Comment: I just wanted to duplicated my package as how my instructor told me so. Thank you for this. CTRL+C and CTRL+V didn't sink in right away.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment on an answer you've given the reason you want to do this: "Now I want to put up a free demo version, with some functionality removed."

Instead of copying all the code to another package I'd take the approach of having only one code base and using a build parameter to specify if you're building the free or commercial version. The classes and config (e.g. spring) that are included in the build could then depend on this parameter.

Duplicating the codebase may seem like the easier option now but will duplicate your work in the long run when maintaining it, and increase the risk of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

How about just extend the classes you want to change? that way you can the two variations in the same package

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much "slight variation" really is you might want to keep it as one package and handle the differences. Reasons you might not want to do this is that by duplicating a whole package for only small changes is not really clean. Duplicated code is a code smell and can cause headaches in the future if a bug is found in one package and needs to be fixed as well in other sections of code.

To answer the question though, Eclipse should have the functionality to copy the whole package and to paste it back into the project. You will have to rename either one of the packages so that you have a unique package name though.